# Is there numpy's method which acts same as tensorflow's embedding_lookup()?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I want to lookup from from matrix by indice

if matrix looks like this

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 6 7 8
>
> 9 2 1 3

and there is indice like

> [1,1,2,0]

So, want I want to do is get

> 5 6 7 8
>
> 5 6 7 8
>
> 9 2 1 3
>
> 1 2 3 4

I can do it by using tensorflow's `embedding_lookup()` or `gather()`

but because of my poor searching skill, I'm having trouble with finding numpy methods for this operation.

is there a method for this operation?

Comment: I found that np.take() support this operation, thanks

Comment: `take` works.  You can also simply index with the list of indices.  E.g. if `x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 2, 1, 3]])`, you can use `x[[1, 1, 2, 0]]`.